# Find where are big jumps in a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector, numeric

Let's say I have a numeric vector with 500 numbers. When sorting them, the numbers are quite close to each other, except for a couple of jumps. Example:

```
v <- c(1565.196, 1567.127, 1569.064, 4255.558, 4256.837, 77240.274, 77247.345)
```

Is there a way to find exactly where those jumps are?

Desired output:

```
Positions: 3-4, 5-6
```

Comment: a naive approach: `which(diff(v) > 100)`

Comment: @rawr you actually gave me an awesome idea:

which(diff(v) > median(v))

That gives exactly what I was looking for!

Thanks :)